# Populating treeview with two tables in database

Tags: database, vb.net, treeview

This is the code I've got from my last question:

```
Dim node As New TreeNode  
Dim lastChapter As String = String.Empty

While dr2.Read()
    Dim curChapter = dr2("chapterno").ToString
    If curChapter Is Nothing OrElse curChapter <> lastChapter Then
        node = New TreeNode(curChapter)
        lastChapter = curChapter
        geo.Nodes("toc").Nodes.Add(node)

    End If
    node.Nodes.Add(dr2("lessonno").ToString)
End While
```

It really helps a lot, but I have a problem. In my system, the chapter table and the lesson table are different tables but connected to each other. Chapter number is foreign key to the lesson table. It may happen that a chapter includes no lesson and I want that chapter to still appear in the treeview (named 'geo').

Big thanks!

Comment: The SQL used for the query would be a nice start - we are guessing otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that your two tables have this schema:

```
table Chapter
    ChapterNo  ==> PK
    Title

table Lesson
    LessonNo   ==> PK 
    Title
    ChapterNo  ==> FK to Chapter
```

Now if you want to retrieve all the chapters and the lessons for the chapters the query to be prepared is something like this

```
SELECT c.ChapterNo, c.Title, l.LessonNo, l.Title
FROM Chapter c LEFT JOIN Lesson l ON c.ChapterNo = l.ChapterNo
```

This will result in a record for every chapter also for chapters without lessons and the same ChapterNo is repeated for each individual lesson associated

The query should be used to populate your DataReader above (the dr2) and a little change is needed in code to avoid an exception when you read a record for a chapter without lessons

```
While dr2.Read()
    ....
    if Not IsDBNull(dr2("Lessonno") Then
        node.Nodes.Add(dr2("lessonno").ToString)
    End If
End While
```

Comment: thanks again @Steve! you really help me a lot! big thanks!!

Comment: but, uhm, why is it that there is a plus sign in the chapter that doesnt have a lesson yet? @Steve?

Comment: but, the plus sign in the chapter node means that there is a child node there, isn't it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behavior. Probably some property setting but I am not sure about it

Comment: ohh, ok sir. but many thanks! i sincerely appreciate your kindness.

Comment: hi sir @Steve, sorry for disturbing you again, but how can i filter the selection by table Chapter's Description? i tried using where-statement but it does not work...

Comment: @ABCDE please post a new question with all the details of your problem. In this way more people will look at your specific problem with higher probability to get a reasoned answer. And you will follow the rules where you should ask a single precise question at time

Comment: ah, sorry again